# Contar Quantidade de Uploads em um Certo Periodo

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho a seguinte query em meu arquivo:

```
SELECT IDUsuario,IDArquivo,Time FROM uploads
    WHERE Time >= '2018-02-20 00:00:00'
    AND Time < '2018-03-21 00:00:00'
```

E o meu resultado assemelha-se a isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso eu tenho ID de usuários repetidos porque eles uparam mais de um arquivo e ganharam ponto por isso , as minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1 - Teria como eu realizar a contagem em uma query so dos IDS de usuários ?
2 - Sé houver , qual seria o melhor método utilizar o php pra realizar a contagem dos usuários ou realizar isso pelo mysql?

Não será algo rotineiro , somente em datas bonus usaremos o sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Teria como eu realizar a contagem em uma query só dos IDS de usuários ?

Sim, é possível contar quantos uploads o usuário fez. Basta utilizar `COUNT` e agrupar pelo `id`. Exemplo:

```
SELECT `id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total FROM `uploads` GROUP BY `id`
```

Aqui ele vai agrupar todos os usuário pelo `ID` e depois vai contar quantos registros aquele `ID` agrupado tem.

E para filtrar pela data, basta utilizar o operador [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). Com esse operador você pode passar a data inicial e a data final. Exemplo:

```
"SELECT `id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total FROM `uploads` WHERE `date_added` BETWEEN '2018-02-20 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-22 00:00:00' GROUP BY `ID`"
```

Aqui ele também vai contar o número de uploads por usuário, porém agora ele irá filtrar entre as datas indicadas.

> Sé houver , qual seria o melhor método utilizar o php pra realizar a contagem dos usuários ou realizar isso pelo mysql?

Você pode fazer isso através do PHP sim, tanto com a biblioteca [MySQLI](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) quanto [PDO](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

**Exemplo com *PDO*:**

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=NOME-DO-BANCO-DE-DADOS;host=localhost", "DB-USUARIO", "DB-SENHA");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total FROM `uploads` WHERE `date_added` BETWEEN '2018-02-20 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-22 00:00:00' GROUP BY `ID`");
$stmt->execute();

var_dump( $stmt->fetchAll() );
```

**Exemplo com *MySQLi*:**

```
<?php

$conn = new MySQLi("localhost", "DB-USUARIO", "DB-SENHA", "NOME-DO-BANCO-DE-DADOS");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT `id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total FROM `uploads` WHERE `date_added` BETWEEN '2018-02-20 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-22 00:00:00' GROUP BY `ID`");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump( $row );
}
```

**Estrutura utilizada no exemplo:**

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| file_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date_added | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

[**Demonstração**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92a284/3)